# Почему не выводится результат сортировки? Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, pdo

Доброго времени суток. Делаю сортировку, но вот столкнулся с проблемой. Пишет, что не найдена функция, когда пишу `alert()`, без `alert()` вообще не работает ничего. Не понимаю в чем причина. 
Сделано 4 файла, чтобы отделить сугубо запросы, обработку и верстку: `index.php`, `functions.php`, `models.php`, `common.js`

Файл **common.js**

```js
  $(".sort span").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".load").fadeIn(1000,function () {
      $.ajax({
        url:'/functions.php',
        data:'sort_id='+id,
        type:'get',
        dataType:'json',

        success:function(html) {
          alert(html);
  
          $(".rest_content").hide().fadeIn(2000);
          $(".fon").css({'display':'none'});
          $(".load").fadeOut(1000);

        }
      });
    });

  });
```

В **index.php** содержится верстка

В **functions.php** содержится обработчики кнопок и т.д.

```
if($_GET['sort_id']) {
$id = $_GET['sort_id'];
$rest  = get_rest($pdo,$id); //на это ругается почему-то. Она не найдена...
exit(json_encode($rest));   
} else {
$rest  = get_rest($pdo);
}
```

В **models.php** содержатся функции с запросами

```
function get_rest($pdo,$id=FALSE) {
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM rest');
if($id) {
   if($id == 'rating') {
   $stmt .= ' ORDER BY raiting ASC';
}
else if ($id == 'name') {
  $stmt .= ' ORDER BY title ASC';
}
else if ($id == 'price_a') {
  $stmt .= ' ORDER BY price ASC';
}
else if ($id == 'price_d') {
  $stmt .= ' ORDER BY price DESC';
}
}
$rest = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $rest;
}
```

Comment: замени `Alert(html)` на `console.log(html)`, и отпиши что получится в консоли

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function  get_rest() in <b>\functions.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

Comment: А файл models.php подключён в functions.php ?

Comment: в head прописан   include 'functions.php'; а head инклюдится в файл index.php

Comment: @PoGiS Ваш скрипт стучится в functions.php, соответственно подключения в index.php не выполняются

Comment: По идее он в functions.php, а сам functions.php находится в head.php, а сам же head.php подключается в index.php. Разве так не подходит?

Comment: @PoGiS, у вас еще и сама функция get_rest() содержит неправильный код.

Comment: @PoGiS, если кратко -- проверяйте порядок включения php файлов. Собственно ни одной инструкции `include/require` в ваших примерах нет, так что все сводится к игре в "угадайку".

Comment: @Visman, подскажите, а что не правильно? Просто pdo 2 дня назад начал разбирать.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я в head include делаю functions, model.

Comment: @PoGiS, сначала сформируйте всю строку sql запроса и только потом делайте сам запрос в данном случае.

Comment: @PoGiS, я даже не представляю _как_ вы это делаете, но, скорее всего, вы делаете это не правильно.

Comment: @Visman, не понимаю. Я объявил функцию, затем в другом документе вызвал ее через переменную. Должна же работать. 
Например, такой код работает. 
Написано в model.php <br/>
  `function get_place($pdo) { <br/>
     $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT place FROM place'); <br/>
      $place = $stmt->fetchAll(); <br/>
      return $place ; <br/>
    }` <br/>
Написано в function.php
$place = get_place _list($pdo);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Переменную `$pdo` не стоит каждый раз передавать в функцию, напишите внутри функции `global $pdo;`
2. В функции `get_rest()` вы сначала делаете запрос, а потом только добавляете к запросу сортировку - так неправильно. Нужно сначала определиться что вы хотите получить в ответе, потом только сделать запрос в базу. Мой вариант кода файла **models.php**:

   ```
   function get_rest($id=FALSE) {
     global $pdo;
     $stmt = 'SELECT * FROM rest';
     if($id) {
       if($id == 'rating') {
         $stmt .= ' ORDER BY raiting ASC';
       }
       else if ($id == 'name') {
         $stmt .= ' ORDER BY title ASC';
       }
       else if ($id == 'price_a') {
         $stmt .= ' ORDER BY price ASC';
       }
       else if ($id == 'price_d') {
         $stmt .= ' ORDER BY price DESC';
       }
     }

     $query = $pdo->query($stmt);
     $rest = $query->fetchAll();
     return $rest;
   }
   ```

Comment: Вроде ошибок нет, но я ничего не получаю.  Идет отправка на сервер, а в тот же alert для проверки что выводится ничего не поступает. 
+ я послушал ваш совет и теперь написал для всех имеющих функций вот такой код(для примера) - http://prntscr.com/8vkrl0 Правильно? Потому что меня смущает, что во всех имеющих функциях у меня объявлена global $pdo. или это так и надо?

Comment: да ничего не выводит. Бесконечно грузит.

Comment: я его специально поместил в файл с функцией. Не работает почему-то

Comment: спасибо большое! Оказывается оба запроса работают. Ошибка была в том, что я случайно удалил exit, когда получал json! Сколько мучался блин)
Кстати, а как правильно код писать, если я хочу получать данные аксом. Для каждого результата создавать свой документ?

Comment: ну вот у меня в functions.php находится сам обработчик(если получили данные, то вып. следующее). Код сдесь -http://prntscr.com/8vldpp 
Есть файл model.php, в котором находятся все функции. http://prntscr.com/8vldx4
Тут 2 проблемы: 
1. Если я оставлю все как есть сейчас, то будет бесконечная загрузка, но, если я помещу функцию из model.php в function.php, то все работает. Я не хочу, чтобы так было. 
2. Однако у меня есть еще 3-й файл - init.php, в котором собственно идет весь инклюд function.php, model.php, dbconnection.  Как быть в таких случаях? Надеюсь, что не сильно запутал вас

Comment: просто файл init.php содержит сугубо подключенные файлы. В нем не желательно писать всю эту ересь с functions.

Comment: оказывается рано радовался. Нажимаю на нужную сортировку, но ничего не сортируется( для вывода блоков делал append)